# Symfony2 Compass Path Mode App Error

Tags: php, ruby, symfony, compass-sass

I'm trying to install Compass in Assetic on Symfony2 and I seem to be running into some problems.  I keep getting this error when I dump the assets:

```
RuntimeError on line ["62"] of /home/psion/.gem/ruby/gems/compass-connector-0.8.2/lib/           
compass-connector.rb: Path mode app is required for partials/base, vendor detected
```

My config files are pretty simple and basic for compass:

```
parameters:
# Assetic
 assetic.filter.compass.images_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../web
 assetic.filter.compass.http_path:ssetic.filter.compass.http_path:  /images

assetic:
debug:          %kernel.debug%
use_controller: false
#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    #closure:
    #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
    #yui_css:
    #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
    sass: ~
    compass: ~
```

Any idea what the error means or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I was using a rather nasty compass-connector and was still calling that connector even when I told Assetic it didn't exist anymore.  Remove the connector, on to the the next error, but that is for another question.